# How to update menu of info directory node?

Tags: info

I've installed some program that added menu items in info directory node (a main menu of `info` command). Then i manually deleted the programs info files from the system, so now when i click on 'program' item, it is not found. However the items of the program are still in the directory node. How does info compile the directory node? How it can be updated, so there are no more this program on the list? And generally how does the mechanism of finding and updating info files work, especially during install and uninstall?

**Edit**: One dirty solution is to just manually delete infofiles from infopath. Also i learned that in every infopath there is a file `dir`, which has links to every info file in the current directory, so one may just edit it instead of deleting files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I never ran it manually before, but `install-info` looks like what you want (if you guessed it has an info manual, you're right, `info install-info` — although [there is a man page](http://xkcd.com/912/), too).

Comment: I couldn't find out, how should i invoke install-info. However i've sold the problem just by doing `sudo rm -rf /usr/local/share/info/`.