# How to automatically update the top info directory

Tags: software-installation, pacman, info

I use [MSYS2](http://sourceforge.net/projects/msys2/) on my Windows machine and when I installed `make`, as a dependency `pacman` installed `guile`. Listing the files of the `guile` package revealed that it has `info` pages (`guile.info.gz`) installed at `/usr/share/info`.

When I enter `info guile`, `info` displays the `guile` node. However, if I navigate to the top node, I don't see Guile listed there; same is the case with just giving `info`. From [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/34092/30580), I found out that there's a `dir` file in each path listed by `$INFOPATH` which is used by `info` to compile the top level node to list all the info nodes installed. I don't see Guile listed in this file.

I realize, from the answer to the linked question, that I may use `install-info` to update the `dir` file with the Guile node.

However, I'd like to know if there's an automatic way of updating all such `dir` files (which is used to show the Top node of `info`) with all such missing info pages; something on the lines of `mandb` used to index for `apropos` and `whatis` automatically periodically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Debian ships a script called [update-info-dir](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man8/update-info-dir.8.html) which does exactly this. I suspect that Debian made its own because there wasn't a standard one at the time. You can grab the script from the [`install-info` binary package](https://packages.debian.org/sid/install-info) or from the [Debian patch part of the source archive](http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian/pool/main/t/texinfo/texinfo_5.2.0.dfsg.1-6.debian.tar.xz) (if this link dies because the version number has changed, [look for a file called `texinfo_*.debian.tar.gz`](http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian/pool/main/t/texinfo/)).

Comment: Good to know there isn't a standard way. Then it looks like Pacman should be doing this when installing info pages, it has done it for the newly installed `make` but missed doing it for its dependency `guile`. Will raise a bug on MSYS2 first. Thanks!

Comment: Apparently it isn't MSYS2's issue but my way of updating the packages, which I've corrected and all is well now :)